# how to add row in other table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table name="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="add"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table name="table2">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                <input type="text"  placeholder="who" name="who" />
                <input type="text"  placeholder="the" name="the" />
                <input type="text"  placeholder="yes" name="yes" />
                        </td>
                    </td>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tejdeep/der3m8qe/)

I have two tables. table1 and table2.

I have "add" button in table1 and "input text " in table2.

By clicking add it should insert new row(input text box).

Comment: Take a look at [**.append()**](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: This is easily done, but what have you tried so far? Just handing you a solution will not help you learn, nor is it the intensions of this site.

Comment: in which table you want to insert the row and what value you need in the newly created row?

Comment: @DevendraSoni In table2

Comment: @Devendra Soni In table2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".button").click(function(){
                    $('.child-table tr:last').after('<tr></tr>');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="button" type="button" value="add"/></td>
                <td>
                    <table class="child-table">
                        <tr><td></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You just want to create a new row. Is that all your requirement??

Comment: I have added the full html. Please try this. It will add a row on each click.(You can remove the input field if you want to)

Comment: removing input it is not adding new row can you check please

Comment: I have edited the code without any input field. please check now.(just inspect the code to see the changes)